# Captured variable is disposed in outer scope

Tags: c#, .net-core, resharper

I have the following piece of sample code to which resharper complains "Captured variable is disposed in outer scope". I do not any issues here as `ExecuteAsync` which calls the unnamed lambda is awaited so httpClient will not be used outside the scope. Is this a false positive?

```
private static async Task MyTestFunction(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) {

            string baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000";
            using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            try {
                await ExecuteAsync(
                    async () => {
                        try {
                            await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(baseUrl)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex);
                            throw;
                        }
                    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func) {
            await func().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Comment: In this instance you shouldn't dispose it at all. Instead cache `HttpClient` in a static field, see https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: That advice is only when you create HttpClient directly, if you are creating via IHttpClientFactory you can dispose the HttpClient because Client factory does not dispose undelaying SockerHandler . See more details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining that `httpClient` won't be disposed until `ExecuteAsync` finished because it's declared early. It could be disposed earlier if you declare it within the inner `try` statement.

Note: this will probably have very little performance benefits if any, ReSharper sticks to a rigid set of rules for things that it flags.

It's also a good idea to make your base url a `const` variable as it never changes.

```
private const string BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8000";

private static async Task MyTestFunction(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) 
{
    try {
        await ExecuteAsync(
            async () => {
                try {
                    using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                    await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(BaseUrl)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    throw;
                }
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

private static async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func) {
    await func().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It complains because there is nothing in the contract of `ExecuteAsync` that requires it to only use the function it receives during its own execution (e.g. it could store it in a `LastExecutedFunction` field).

If you are using the JetBrains annotations, mark the `func` parameter as `[InstantHandle]` to explicitly document that the method will immediately use that parameter. The Rider/R# will know that disposing it in the caller is perfectly safe.

I don't think there is currently a way to do a similar marking using only system attributes.